# How to get Individual geometry elements of Fusion Table in earth engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

I have a fusion table and it content several points. I have also created NDVI layer. Now i need to print  NDVI value of individual pixels associated with point ids(taken from fusion table). But i don't know how to do that. To track the point id of fusion table i tried to print point features. I have written the following codes for the same. Console pictures is attached to which ids i want to get.Also sharing the GEE link[Code link](https://code.earthengine.google.co.in/cf1aa5c221a40a861620a483f86fde5a) [Exmp: [Need to know the ndvi value for id 3]]

```
    // ---------Cloud Masking function

function maskS2clouds(image) {
  var qa = image.select('QA60');

  // Bits 10 and 11 are clouds and cirrus, respectively.
  var cloudBitMask = ee.Number(2).pow(10).int();
  var cirrusBitMask = ee.Number(2).pow(11).int();

  // Both flags should be set to zero, indicating clear conditions
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0).and(
             qa.bitwiseAnd(cirrusBitMask).eq(0));

  // Return the masked and scaled data.
  return image.updateMask(mask).divide(10000);
}



var boundary = ee.FeatureCollection('ft:1T-XrxMki2k49fhQdhMxesWKBoyyUJiKN70pErh9z');// Boundary
var gtpoints = ee.FeatureCollection('ft:1ZvFeFO5jHGo3VExlKNc-kdL-3hmJSeyfLzqLvHhy');//Co-ordinates
print(gtpoints);
var test = gtpoints.features;
print(test);
Map.centerObject(boundary);
// ---------  Import of Images (Sentinel _ 2 multispectral)


var image = ee.ImageCollection(sent2img
.filterDate("2018-09-22","2018-10-23")
.filterBounds(boundary)
.map(maskS2clouds)
.sort("CLOUD_COVERAGE_ASSESSMENT")
.median()
);

//----------  Preprocessing 

var mosaic = image.mosaic()
var clip = mosaic.clip(boundary);
print('clip', clip);


//----------   FCC creation and visualisation of AOI     
Map.addLayer(clip, {bands: ['B8','B4','B3'], min: 0, max: 0.3},'clip');


var ndvi = clip.expression(
    ' ((NIR - RED) / (NIR + RED))', {
      'NIR': clip.select('B8'),
      'RED': clip.select('B4'),
}).rename('nd');

var palette = ['196fda', 'CE7E45', 'DF923D', 'F1B555', 'FCD163', '99B718',
               '74A901', '66A000', '529400', '3E8601', '207401', '056201',
               '004C00', '023B01', '012E01', '011D01', '011301'];

Map.addLayer(ndvi, {min:0, max:1, palette: palette},"NDVI");
```

Comment: Hi Avik. What have you tried? You should post some code so we can see what you're trying to do and how to help you.

Comment: https://code.earthengine.google.co.in/f6373814c7dc6484f0c77e7f8dd50e7e

Comment: shared my half done code,

Comment: @AvikBetal Please edit your question with the additional information. Comments are considered "non permanent" and new information should be added to the question itself.

Comment: You don't have to post the entire code if you don't want, you could just post a sample code to reproduce the error or the task you are having trouble with

Comment: Hi, this is sample link https://code.earthengine.google.co.in/cf1aa5c221a40a861620a483f86fde5a

Comment: Hi, Edited the question and also updated the link of sample code with the entire code. @Rodrigo any idea how can i get the detailed information of featurecollection which taken from fusion table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this code to the sample code to get each point ndvi:

```js
// Get NDVI in each point
var points_ndvi = ndvi.reduceRegions({
  collection: gtpoints,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.first(),
  scale: 10
})

// Rename
var properties = ee.Feature(points_ndvi.first()).propertyNames()
var new_names = properties.replace('first', 'ndvi')
points_ndvi = points_ndvi.select(properties, new_names)

// You can export it as a table
// Export.table.toDrive(points_ndvi, 'description', 'folder', 'fileNamePrefix', 'CSV')

// Pretty Print
var points_list = points_ndvi.toList(points_ndvi.size())
var points_ids = points_list.map(function(ft) {return ee.String(ee.Feature(ft).id())})
var points_values = points_list.map(function(ft) {return ee.String(ee.Feature(ft).get('ndvi'))})

print(ee.Dictionary.fromLists(points_ids, points_values))
```

https://code.earthengine.google.co.in/c78a6e70c646eb9cdec149657cb839f6

Answer (score 1):

[image: Red color showing the function i used]

I used the following function : filter(ee.Filter.metadata(...))